# Linq GetType GetProperties base on List

Tags: c#, linq

I have this `viewModel` where I like to check the `accessGroupList` has any value of True and set `baccess` base on that value. If they are both false it then `baccess` would be false but if one of them is true `baccess` would be true.

```
 MemberViewModel result = new MemberViewModel();
 result.IsPractices = true;
 result.IsUser = false;


 var accessGroupList = new List<string>();

 accessGroupList.Add("IsUser");
 accessGroupList.Add("IsBestPractices");

 var baccess = result.GetType().GetProperties().First(o => o.Name == accessGroupList).GetValue(result, null);



  bool? baccess = Property as bool?;
```

Comment: i try to rephrase your question for clarification: I would like to check in `result` if any of the properties from the list `accessGroupList` are true, and if so set the value of `baccess` also to true, false otherwise..... please correct me if I misunderstood you somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create this simple console project. You can do this, remove comment from where for using in your project

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cl = new MyClass();
            cl._item1 = false;
            cl._item2 = false;

            var a = cl.GetType().GetProperties()
                //.Where(x => accessGroupList.Contains(x.Name))
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    name = x.Name,
                    value = (bool)x.GetValue(cl, null)
                })
                .Any(x => x.value);
                

            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public bool _item1 { get; set; }
        public bool _item2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var baccess = result.GetType().GetProperties()
.Where(o => accessGroupList.Any(propName => Equals(propName, o.Name))
.Select(x => (bool)x.GetValue(result, null))
.Any(val => val);
```

Your problem is that you were using .First (which will only return one item) but then in there, you're also comparing the property name to the list itself. You need to do another linq operation to get the appropriate properties out, then you can check if any of those properties have a value of true

Answer (score 1):

First of all note that `accessGroupList` is list and you need to use `Contains` or `Any` to compare it with property name. Then you can select the value of those property that appeared in `accessGroupList`

```
var baccess = result.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(o => accessGroupList.Contains(o.Name))
    .Select(t=>(bool)t.GetValue(result, null));
```